# Undefined local variable or method 'f' - Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

I am working from a tutorial. No matter what I do this error still keeps coming back, would like to know the reason for this.  This is driving me nuts. I believe I am using the correct indenting of haml, as this doesn't come up with a syntax error. And yes I do have the haml, bootstrap and simple_form gems installed.

I have a controller called pins_controller where I have defined the following:

```
def new
    @pin = Pin.new
end

def create
    @pin = Pin.new(pin_params)

    if @pin.save
        redirect_to @pin, notice: "Successfully saved new pin"
    else 
        render 'new'
    end
end

private

def pin_params
    params.require(:pin).permit(:title, :description)
end
```

And here's my code for the view file which renders the error:

```
= simple_form_for @pin, html: {multipart: true} do |f|
  - if @pin.errors.any?
    #errors
      %h2
      = pluralize(@pin.errors.count, "error")
      prevented this Pin from saving
      %ul
        - @pin.errors.full_messages.each do |msg|
          %li = msg
.form-group
  = f.input :title, input_html: { class: 'form-control' }
.form-group
  = f.input :description, input_html: { class: 'form-control'}
= f.button :submit, class: "btn btn-primary"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the haml is formatted correctly (sometimes I have trouble with SO code), your problem is your indentation. Everything from `.form-group` down needs to be indented another few spaces so that the structure matches up with line 2.

I'm sure you've read that haml is whitespace sensitive (which is weird for some) but if your indentation is wrong then it won't show up. So since you're out dented the last few lines you're referencing the block argument (f) but it's not in scope.

Right now the haml is interpreting that your `do |f|` block ends at the line

```
    - @pin.errors.full_messages.each do |msg|
      %li = msg
```

Try changing that up and see if that error goes away.

Comment: Hey thanks a lot @cdownard! I lined up the '.form-group' with the '- if @pin.errors.any?' and it worked. The input fields were indented further. Thanks again. Now I can move forward.